# Looping 10 possible N samples and calculate sums of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, matrix, apply

I'm generating `n` samples, each of dimension `m`, and I populate a matrix `mxn`. Then I use the `apply` function to go for every column of the matrix (every sample generated) and return a list with the sum for the elements of each column. At the end I calculate the mean of all of those sums.

```
data = replicate(n, rnorm(m, mean = mu, sd = variance))

sum_of_column <- function(col) {
  s <- sum(col)
}

sums <- apply(data, 2, sum_of_column)
me <- mean(sums)
```

`sums` is the list where each index is the sum of the respective column. `me` is the mean of that list.

But `n` is a single value and I want it to be a list of numbers (like `1:10`), meaning I want to do this algorithm for every possible `n = 1, n = 2, n = ... , n = 10` for which I need to store `sums` and calculate their `mean`. I may end up with a bidimensional array (as dataframe) where one column are the `n`'s and the other column the correspondent mean of `sums` for that `n`.

In other words, I need to loop this algorithm I coded and store the value for each `n`-iteration. Like

```
n  mean(sums)
1     123
2     13
...
10    94
```

I thought of doing this with a `for` loop, but would there be a smarter way to do this without explicitly looping? Maybe using apply for 3 dimensions?

Comment: Columns of data frames aren’t really first class objects in R. You should try colSums or lapply( data, sum).

Comment: Note that you could reduce the above to `mean(replicate(n, sum(rnorm(m, mean = mu, sd = variance))))`,hence to have `n<-1:10` you could use a loop/apply family eg `sapply(1:10, function(n)mean(replicate(n, sum(rnorm(m, mean = mu, sd = variance)))))`

Comment: @Onyambu That looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the logic into a function `FUN`. In its arguments, predefine `m`, `mu`, and `sigma`. `n` will be defined dynamically in the loop.

```
FUN <- \(n, m=1e5, mu=0, sigma=1) {
  mxn <- replicate(n, rnorm(m, mean=mu, sd=sigma))
  return(c(n=n, mean_of_sums=mean(colSums(mxn))))
}

FUN(1)
#   n mean_of_sums
# 1 1    -226.6016
```

To loop over the `n`, you could use `vapply`, which is similar to `sapply`, but predefines `FUN.VALUE` in the third argument which saves work for R and, thus, is faster. To get the `n` into rows, you want to `t`ranspose the result.

```
n <- 1:100
set.seed(42)
r <- t(vapply(n, \(n) FUN(n), c(0, 0)))
r <- as.data.frame(r)  ## if wanted
head(r)
#   n mean_of_sums
# 1 1    -412.6182
# 2 2    -114.6650
# 3 3     304.1592
# 4 4      75.8026
# 5 5    -208.2705
# 6 6     126.6526

plot(r, type='l', col=4)
abline(h=0, col=8)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the "\" in `FUN` and then in the 2nd argument to `vapply`? That's totally new to me.

Comment: @JohnPolo In R version >= 4.1 you can write shortly `\(x)` for `function(x)`. Update R, or `FUN <- function(n, ...`  and `t(vapply(n, function(n) FUN(n), c(0, 0)))`.